# ¿Como se envía un objeto javascript { } a un servidor?, sin convertirlo en json

Tags: javascript, post, objeto, fetch, javascript-objeto

envió al servidor un objeto porque es así como lo quiero usar en el servidor y quiero guardarlo tal y como viene, siendo un objeto, comúnmente se suele transformar un objeto javascript a json para que el servidor pueda manejarlo pero eso no me interesa he investigado sobre formData y eso esta bien pero alguien sabe si específicamente se puede enviar al servidor un objeto javascript asumiendo que el servidor use también javascript como lenguaje de servidor.

no quiero usar `JSON.stringify(obj)`

ejemplo del objeto.

```js
var obj = {

    "name": "username",
    "userid": "9999",

    "object1": {
        "subObject1": {
            "subArray1": [],
            "subArray2": []
        },
        "subObject2": {
            "subArray3": [],
            "subArray4": []
        }
    },
    "object2": {
        "subObject3": {
            "subArray5": [],
            "subArray6": []
        }
    },
    "array1": [],
    "array2": []
};
```

Comment: El unico servidor que podria manejar un objeto `JSON` de `javascript` es javascript, puesto que `JSON` significa JavaScript Object Notation, asi que a no ser de que del lado del backend estes usando `nodejs` lo mas recomendable y viable seria siempre enviar esta data como un `JSON` y no como un objeto de javascript.

Comment: No has mencionado que lenguaje estas utilizando en el servidor, depende mucho de este el como podrás abordar el problema, en PHP por ejemplo puedes enviarlo como un string, con la estructura que usa para enviar parámetros GET una URL https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-str.php

Comment: Si solo quieres enviarlo como tal para desues usarlos, por que no intentas enviarlo como string quiza con llas comillas inversas o tacktics de javascript y ya en el servidor o transformas?

Answer (score 1):

Una respuesta de las fáciles: **no puedes**.

La única forma en la que podrías hacer eso sería enviando los *bytes* en crudo (*raw*), lo cual depende de que el lenguaje te permitiera acceder a ello ... cosa que Javascript (y prácticamente ningún otro lenguaje *interpretado* te permitirán).

Y, aunque pudieras, luego te quedaría la parte *complementaria*, tratar esos datos en el servidor.

- Cosas tales como punteros a memoria serían completamente intratables: las direcciones de memoria usadas serían desde el punto de vista **del cliente**, y no coincidirán **en absoluto** con las direcciones usadas por el servidor.
- Aunque se usen formas de direccionamiento independientes de la máquina, todavía te quedaría el problema de los distintos tipos *nativos*: ancho en *bytes*, *endian*, ...
- Aunque tuvieras la seguridad 100% de lo anterior, todavía tendrías que tratar el problema del cambio de formato en distintos intérpretes del enguaje. Un navegador empleará datos internos completamente distintos de los empleados por otro navegador distinto.

Para evitar todos esos problemas, se crearon los Formatos de Intercambio de Datos ... de los cuales, JSON es uno de los mas utilizados :-)

Ya si nos ponemos *a las malas*, siempre puedes crear tu propio formato de intercambio de datos ... con lo cual tendrás un montón de trabajo y, al estar realizado en Javascript (que no es lo más rápido del mundo), sería mas lento que una simple llamada a `JSON.stringify( )`. Con lo cual habrás *reinventado la rueda* para obtener todas las ventajas **que ya tenías** usando JSON.

Como último punto, **existen** ciertos formatos alternativos (como el [`msgpack`](https://msgpack.org/)), los cuales pueden ser alternativas en ciertos casos. Pero cada uno de ellos tiene su propia API y su propia forma de uso.